# Calculating average age in Python

Tags: python, django

I am using Django and trying to calculate the average client age, and for some reason this answer is escaping me.  What I want to do is to loop through all clients in a group and get the mean delta of today and their dob.

Here is what the model looks like:

```
class Client (models.model):
  ...
  dob = models.DateField(
                         null = False
                        )
```

So that I am trying to do something like this:

```
def age(self,qrydtm=date.today())
  # here is a method (from funcs.py) that returns a list of dob for the group
  delta = 
  delta_m = ((qrydate.year - self.dob.year)*12)+(qrydate.month - self.dob.month)         
  years = delta_m // 12
  weeks = delta // 7
  months = (delta_m - (years*12))
  if (years > 0):
    return ('%s yr - %s mn' % (years,months))
  else:
    return ('%s wk' % (weeks))
```

The method I am using, creates a list of dob like this [(datetime.date(1976, 8, 4),), (datetime.date(2005, 8, 8),), (datetime.date(1986, 10, 14),)]

Comment: You are using django right? Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/, it might help

Comment: Which database backend are you using?

Comment: The database backend is postgre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the average age as a timedelta:

```
l = [datetime.date(1976, 8, 4), datetime.date(2005, 8, 8), ...] # values_list(flat=True)
today = datetime.date.today()
average_age = sum(map(lambda x: today-x, l), datetime.timedelta(0))/len(l)
```

**Edit:**

With l being potentielly large I avoided the second list:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
l = [date(1976, 8, 4), date(2005, 8, 8), ...] # values_list(flat=True)
today = date.today()
average_age = sum((today - x for x in l), timedelta(0)) / len(l)
```

Comment: I imported timedelta and got: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'.

Comment: @David__: Did you see the "today-x" part of the example?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to mention I had defined today that way.

Comment: @S.Lorr: I included the "today-x".  Why does it work for you as written?

Comment: I should mention that when I set 'l' and 'today', I have to leave off the datetime and shorten to date.today and date(2005, 8, 8).

Comment: @David__ you like it better now? Btw: What is the expected size of the dataset?

Comment: Your edit works perfect.  thank you.  normally this will be 100-1000 records, but on occasion could be for 10k.  Why would you suggest something else in that case?

Comment: No, I think it's a valid solution for that size. On my laptop (core2duo 2.26ghz) it has a runtime of 0.2 seconds for 500000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adapted solution of the accepted answer using `relativedelta` which is more descriptive:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
l = [date(2006, 9, 17), date(2004, 9, 17), ]
today = date.today()
average_age = sum((relativedelta(today, x) for x in l), relativedelta(0)) / len(l)
```

Then `average_age` outputs `relativedelta(years=+11, months=+4, days=+17)`